# How to find the difference between 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Table1

```
id no name value

001 grid1 rajan 200
001 grid2 rajan 300
002 grid1 mahesh 100
002 grid2 mahesh 200
003 grid1 jayan 200
003 grid2 jayan 50
```

I want to find the difference (GRID1 - GRID2) for each id

Expected output

```
id  name value

001 rajan -100
002 mahesh -100
003 jayan 150
```

How to make a query for the above condition

Need query help

Comment: how do you know that for mahesh it should be 100-200 and not 200-100 ?

Comment: i think you missed -100 on rajan, right?

Comment: @Grisha, it will be always grid1 - grid2 only

Answer (score 4):

```
select id, name, sum(case when no = 'grid1' then value else value*(-1) end)
from table1
group by id, name
```

see [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/854b9/1) Demo